# Using git to manage website-based user documents

Tags: web-applications, version-control, document-management

I am doing some research to determine whether and how I can set up a website that will allow visitors with user accounts to create, edit and share documents using a custom document format.  The documents will contain text data (e.g. JSON and/or XML) and pointers to various types of binary media files.  I would like to put the text and binary documents under version control as well, so I can eventually develop a front-end that will allow users to view or compare older document versions.  What kind of options would make sense to store these documents?

Comment: Note that git is not built for storing binary data. It surely can do it, but it will incur you a performance penalty in the long term, especially if the files are big. If you are to store large files, it may be worthwhile taking a look at git-annex (or git-media).

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at those for the binary files.  I guess what I'm wondering is should I try to store files in git repos on my own server (or a data server), or use something external like GitHub, or something else entirely?